# Flutter Alignment doesn't responds to edit

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a stack with 2 widgets: Image and Row with text. I created Align widget to make alignment to text. But it doesn't work right. It automatically places text to topright, no matter how i edit Alignment(0.5, 0.5)

```
    class GameCard extends StatelessWidget {
      GameCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      List<String> gametags_list = ['First Person Shooter', 'RPG', 'Tower Defence'];
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Stack(
            children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            height: 250,
            width: 380,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                image: const DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(
                        'https://cdn.ag.ru/media/games/72e/72e0e063c817e90c696b2da3ea78abaa.jpg'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill)),
          ),

// alignment

          Align(
            alignment: Alignment(0.5, 0.9),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const Text(
                  'GAME #1',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 25),
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  child: Text(
                    gametags_list[0],
                    style:
                        const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ]);
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: try use `Positioned` instead of `Align`

Comment: you can return padding instead of stack for your case. This will simplify the design process.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Align widget with Padding and add same padding value that your Container has and Alignment.topLeft to align to top left:

```
Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Column(
              children: [...],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

[image: demo]